# Remove link from .phone element

Tags: html, css

I've added in a widget in my footer (I use Wordpress) which shows a phone number, however for some reason it turns the number into a link.

How can I remove the link? I've looked in my style sheet but can't find any reference to a link, I even tried:

```
a.phonelink:hover { color: #000000; }
```

But this didn't work (phone link color is also black).

Please help!

My site can be seen at:

```
http://www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/
```

For your convenience I've also made a picture explaining the issue:

```
www.reading-college.ac.uk/sites/default/files/phone-link-issue.jpg
```

I usually do something wrong when I post a question (posting a link, not posting a link ect), so I apologise in advance to those hard to please coders!

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: I believe Opera Coast and Safari on iOS all do this automatically by default, because it's easier to tap a link to call someone than highlight it, copy and paste it to make a call. Is this where you're seeing it? On a phone?

Comment: Why did you wrap it in `<a href>` if you don't want it to be a link?

Comment: No, this is in Chrome & IE.

Comment: As I said before, this is a widget in my footer (using Wordpress) I never hard coded this myself. So never wrapped it in a 
    <a href>

Comment: Well, fix the widget

Comment: Please explain what I need to do to "fix the widget".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't have enough specificity. Just use:

```
.pc_info_widget .phone a:hover { color: #000; }
```

and it will fix your issue, assuming there isn't any other CSS with higher specificity that is overriding it.

Comment: A dirty workaround, but worked perfectly. Thank-you!

Comment: but the problem is its still have `<a>` tag.

Comment: @KheemaPandey the **real** problem is that it was turning white on hover, rather than that it's a link. Sometimes it's about reading the question and working out the intention, rather than just answering what the question asks.

Comment: If OP accepted the answer then there is no room for any arguments here.

Comment: Thanks @setek very true, would also like to thank Kheema

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped it in `<a>` tag and that is the reason it has become a link

```
<a href="tel:01865 551521">01865 551521</a>
```

Instead of above simply do

```
 <span>01865 551521</span>
```

**OR** remove **href** tag

```
  <a>01865 551521</a>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the phone number is pulled in through an "info box" widget placed into my footer (I use Wordpress). Unless you can suggest where I can make this edit?

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple line of jquery code you can remove `a` tag. just put this code on any `.js` file and make sure you've included jquery CDN library.

Check **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lonuralijahi/1/edit)**.

**jquery code**

```
$("span.phone a").replaceWith($("span.phone a").text());
```

**Update:**

A simple CSS solution is here. see **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mipiqibozoko/1/edit)**.

```
span.phone a:hover[href^="tel"]{color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: Hey Kheema, this did work. Though I'm new to JQuery so was a little confused - my phone number also turned to color white after I used your code, so will stick to @setek answer. Many thanks for your help. Would vote up but not enough rep :/

Comment: Thank-you Kheema, how could I make my phone number appear in black when it's not a link (post jquery)?

Comment: I tried this but still the phone number is in white? (See my site)
    www.oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk

Comment: No it say's:
    a.footerlink:hover { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }

Besides now it's not a link shouldn't it revert to black?

Comment: What do you mean by more CSS specificity?

Comment: We seem to be kicking cans here, I think I'll leave it as a link but masked on hover as the same color. Many thanks for your help all the same. Could well be skype causing the problem.

Comment: We seem to be kicking cans here, I think I'll leave it as a link but masked on hover as the same color. Many thanks for your help all the same. Could well be skype causing the problem.

Comment: yep lets close this discussion, as your problem solved.